# Azure blob put - image corrupt

Tags: angularjs, azure, azure-blob-storage, ng-file-upload

I'm trying to use the azure storage blob to put an item on it.
It works fine with PDF, MP3 but, when I upload an **IMAGE** file (or TXT file) the file has changed.

When I download the pdf or the mp3, the file is readable. But for the image, it says that it's corrupt ... 
However the TXT file is readable but the content is surrounded by the **webkitfromboundary**

I thinks this is the reason why image don't work...

Exemple :

TXT file with `hello word` only ->

```
------WebKitFormBoundary3rxc8zHbnz4expeP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

hello word
------WebKitFormBoundary3rxc8zHbnz4expeP--
```

So I guess this is the reason why images don't work

---

so this is my upload (from **angularJS**) --- I Use https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

```
Upload.upload
  url: url
  method: 'PUT'
  headers: head
  file: file
  .success (data, status, headers, config) ->
    console.log("SUCCES!!!")
```

value of `head` - ( for an text file)

```
{"x-ms-version":"2014-02-14","x-ms-blob-type":"BlockBlob","x-ms-date":"2015-11-06 10:02:24 GMT","Authorization":"SharedKey generate_key","Content-Type":"text/plain"}
```

ofcourse, the content-type change when this is an image (it takes **file.type** )

---

If it can help, this is the **request headers** from the network page ->

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:fr,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:214
Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8
Host:myaccount.blob.core.windows.net
Origin:http://localhost:9000
Referer:http://localhost:9000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36
```

and the **request payload** ->

```
------WebKitFormBoundary3rxc8zHbnz4expeP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain


------WebKitFormBoundary3rxc8zHbnz4expeP--
```

---

So, anyone has an idea ?

Comment: Seems like an azure storage blob issue.

Comment: Are you still seeing this issue?

Comment: Hi, no I'm not seeing this, I've found the solution, i'll post it in 5mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anwser was that the `Content-Type` sent in the http request was never the good type.

It's because

```
Upload.upload
```

doesn't allow you to change it.

**BUT** you can use the `http` method of the same library, and it'll work like that :

```
  Upload.http
    url: uploadInfo.url
    method: 'PUT'
    headers: {
    "Content-Type": file.type
    [other headers ...]
  }
  data: file
```

and there you go ! it works !